# Relativizer vs relative pronoun

Tags: grammar

Are they synonymous? I don't quite see the difference between them.

1. What are some of the relativizers which are not relative pronouns (if any)?
2. What are some of the relative pronouns which are not relativizers (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're only synonymous if all relativizers (or more simply, "relative words") are pronouns.  In English, some belong to other parts of speech.

*When* and *where* are often considered relative adverbs, not pronouns, in traditional grammar.  If you follow Jespersen and permit intransitive prepositions in your grammar, then these are more naturally considered relative prepositions.

*What* is often a relative pronoun, but sometimes it's a relative determiner (or "determinative" if you use Huddleston & Pullum's terminology).

*That* is traditionally considered a relative pronoun, but some linguists argue that it's not a relative pronoun at all, but the same marker of subordination found in declarative content clauses marked by *that*.  In Huddleston & Pullum's grammar, that makes it a subordinator rather than a relative pronoun.  Whether you consider this a "relativizer" depends on the grammatical framework you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot grasp all those terminologies at once but it's at least good to know they exist.